# Zipping all files in dir - leads to corrupt zip file (mac) when starting from subdir

Tags: bash

I have a weird problem - I want to zip all files in a dir (except 1 folder) via terminal (shell script in the end).

If I do this in the root of the directly I want to zip - everything is fine.

If I do this, starting from a subfolder (e.g. `/scripts` = I want to finally have a shell script which should run) I receive a corrupt zip file that cant be opened by Mac OS Archive Utility (`Error Message: The archive "man_backup_sub.zip" is empty`). The zip file is not empty and I can fully unzip it with a 3rd party tool - and from number of files it has the same amount of files as the "working" zip file.

Folder structure:

```
/
   /backups 
   /index.html
   ....
   /scripts
   /subfolder
   /subfolder/file1.html
```

Command creating a good zip file (current dir is /):

```
zip -r ./_backups/man_backup.zip ./ -x ./_backups/*
```

Command creating a file not working (but being equally in size and content as above); (current dir is */scripts*):

```
zip -r ./../_backups/man_backup_sub.zip ./../ -x ./../_backups/*
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks, br, Rene

Answer (score 0):

So far - didn't find an answer to the problem.

But I found a solution for my case:
So I just finalized the shell script and just moved 1 folder up (cd ..) and ran the command that was working.